# Structuring an XHR request properly with Requests [python]

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to do some web scraping of a site that generates it's data via Javascript.  I've done enough reading on here to know by now that the way to scrape these is to:

1. Watch the network tab in Firebug for what happens when you make the request
2. Isolate the XHR requests and recreate them in a script.

So, when I do 1, a POST request is sent to the link visible in this screenshot:
[image]
and you can also see the response it gets.  Looks great, right?

But when I try and recreate that request & response, with the payload that I see under the Post tab in Firebug, in Python like so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {"Max":999,"RectCoord":"89,-179,-89,179","Source":"","SortField":"NEWID()","OfficeName":"","FirstName"
:"","LastName":"da","CityName":"","ZipCode":"","Category":"S","SecLanguageReq":"","OfficeCode":""}

r = requests.post('http://search.cnyrealtor.com/MyAjaxService.asmx/MemberSearch', data=payload)

print(r.content)
```

I get a page that displays an error message:
`Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in \'/MemberSearch\'`

So, my question is - why am I getting that response when the response in Firebug works fine?  Am I missing something in my `requests.post(url)` line in the Python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dump the dictionary into JSON and send as a payload. It is important to set the `Content-Type` request header as well:

```
import json
import requests

payload = {"Max": 999, "RectCoord": "89,-179,-89,179", "Source": "", "SortField": "NEWID()", "OfficeName": "",
           "FirstName": "", "LastName": "", "CityName": "", "ZipCode": "", "Category": "S", "SecLanguageReq": "",
           "OfficeCode": ""}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("http://search.cnyrealtor.com/SiteContent/SYR/MemberSearchSYR.aspx")
    r = session.post('http://search.cnyrealtor.com/MyAjaxService.asmx/MemberSearch', data=json.dumps(payload),
                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"})

    print(r.content)
```